# Bevel Node don't catch on all sides/edges of a basic object for edgewear

Tags: node-editor, bevel

I'm trying to use the bevel node to do edge wear on object, but it doesn't work out as expected at all :

i'm using the bevel node to do edgewear on simple meshes, as Pointiness node don't work well on low poly.
However, the bevel node when used by itsef in a color ramp into a BSDF don't catch on every edge it seems ?
And when using a setup that use a crossproduct with normals, it only works on one side of the edge ?

My question is : how can i get a edge wear on ALL edges and not just a few, or only on "one face forming the edge"

[image]

I've also tried this node setup , but it only catch on one face that creates the edge...

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close!

This does not work of course because the cross product of these two vectors can be negative. Convert negative to positive using abs math node:

[image]